# Is it possible to debug Windows Service merged with ILMerge

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, ilmerge

I am trying to debug a Windows service whose EXE has been merged with some third party DLLs using ILMerge. It's managed code, C#.  ILMerge has also merged the PDB files into a single `MyMergedService.pdb` file.  The service has been installed not with `installutil.exe` but with this code:

```
 ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

The service installs and starts as it should.

When I attach to the service process exe from within the Visual Studio debugger and try to set a breakpoint, the tooltip error is "the breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

What steps are required to debug a service merged in this way? The reason I'm using ILMerge is that I could not get the service to install properly to begin with. For some reason the external third party DLLs could never be found by `installutil` even though they had been "Copied Local" to the same folder the EXE was in, and I did make sure they were there.

Comment: I suggest to open the modules menu to identify where it tries to load the symbol from ( or to force load them) . To access the modules menu click on the Debug menu, choose Windows, and then click Modules.

Comment: let me know if that works for you or give you additional info in order to post it as anwser for others too...s

Comment: When I follow the suggestion, I get a list of modules, but the `Symbol Status` of my service exe is "Binary was not built with debug information.".

Comment: which explain why you can't debug it. since the code wasn't build in debug but in release , no PDBs are available to VS environment in order to debug the code. if such , you can try the following - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the C# tag to clarify. I don't have the C/C++ options mentioned on the page you linked to.

Comment: Instead of using IL Merge I would suggest using the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and loading the merged assemblies from embedded resources. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx), it the comments of the article the author of IL Merge (search for "Mike Barnett" on the page) said "*As the author of ILMerge, I think this is fantastic! If I had known about this, I never would have written ILMerge.*"

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I did see that, but it was not clear to me where exactly that code should be placed.

Comment: I tried putting  it in Main, but the install never succeeded.

Comment: Please try  - http://candordeveloper.com/2012/12/27/debugging-a-windows-service-application-without-install/